# Jenkins Amazon EC2 plugin and proxy

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, proxy

I am trying to use the Amazon EC2 jenkins plugin. But when I configure it I get:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:337)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
Caused: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to sts.amazonaws.com:443 [sts.amazonaws.com/54.239.29.25] failed:
...
```

I assume this is, because sts.amazonaws.com is reachable only through a proxy from the jenkins instance.

Can I somehow make the plugin use the proxy?

Comment: Have you tried with a proxy..?

Comment: How do I add a proxy?

Comment: Go to your box and set "export http_proxy=<your_proxy>"

Comment: Ok, I already did that. It does not seem to affect the proxy configuration for the falling call.